# Google Sheets, Macro to update a field once an hour has passed based on timestamp in another cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, macros

I'm trying to update a field once an hour has passed from a timestamp.

The Timestamps are placed by a Macro(Which I did not make myself) in the cells on Column C.
The Fields that I want to update an hour after are in the cells on Column D

Here's a link to the practice sheet I'm working on.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s703NMmRQ4ZXqCD6Aaga5P0LZWDZiZZEAWBUkdDUtu0/edit?usp=sharing

Here's how its working now.

- Once someone updates a cell in Column D to say "Work in Progress" or "Completed" a Timestamp is made in Column C.

Now I'm trying to make a Separate Macro.  I'd like this Marco to use the timestamp created in a cell from Column C and, once an hour passes, update the corresponding cell in Column D With "Ready!"

The only problem is I have no idea where to start.  I've tried brainstorming on my own and looking online, but nothing seems to relate to what I'm trying to accomplish here.
Would anyone have any direction they could offer?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Please post an a table of your data

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a time based trigger that calls makeitready() at least every hour.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const list = ["Work in Progress", "Completed"];
  const idx = list.indexOf(e.value);
  if (sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 4 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && ~idx) {
    e.range.offset(0, -1).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
function makeitready() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1, sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const dt = new Date();
  vs.forEach((r,i) => {
    let d = new Date(r[2]);
    let h = myhours(d,dt)
    if((r[3] == "Work in Progress" || r[3] == "Completed") && h >= 1 ) {
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValue("Ready!");
    }
  })
}

function myhours(Start,End) {
  if(Start && End) {
    var second=1000;
    var minute=60*second;
    var hour=minute*60;
    var day=hour*24;
    var t1=new Date(Start).valueOf();
    var t2=new Date(End).valueOf();
    var d=t2-t1;
    var days=Math.floor(d/day);
    var hours=Math.floor(d%day/hour);
    var minutes=Math.floor(d%day%hour/minute);
    //return 'dd:hh:mm:ss\n' + days + ':' + hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;  
    //return d/day;
    return hours + minutes/60;
  }
}
```

Sheet0:

[image]

References:

- [ref1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [ref2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)